# How do you find an empty cell if isBlank is not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a spreadsheet with Google responses.

I want to find then empty cell and then add a random number to that cell on submitting from google forms.

I have the number generator working but I am getting a "Cannot find function isBlank in object."  on line 8.  The rest of the code works but I am new to scripts so I am at a total loss.  Thank you for any help.

````
var id = create_id();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = ss.getRange("'Form Responses 1'!A2:H150");
var rws = r.getNumRows();
var ax=r.getCell(rws-1, 7).getValue();
if(ax.isBlank()){
 r.getCell(rws-1, 7).setValue(id);
}
}//finds empty cell in column 7

function create_id(){
var script_properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var keys = script_properties.getKeys();

var id = new_id();

if(keys.indexOf(id) >=0){
 id = new_id();
}else{
 script_properties.setProperty(id,new Date());
}//uses script 
}  

function getRndNumber(min, max){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}//gets random number

function new_id(){
var rndNum = getRndNumber(1, 99999);
var id = ('0000'+rndNum).slice(-5);
id = id;
return id;
}//send random number to var id ```
````

Comment: Have you tried checking for `""` or `" "` instead? Sometimes is-blank is a little different than null or whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function findAnEmptyCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange("A2:H150");
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var ax=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()-2,7).getValue();
  if(ax==''){
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()-2,7).setValue(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either `ax == ""` or `ax == ''` as [xTwisteDx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12417531/xtwistedx) has said.